# How to get all text view values and pass it through intent android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, textview

How can I get all textviews values and pass it through intent to another activity at once? Here is my source code:

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView imgThumbnail;
    public TextView tvspecies;
    public View view;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view = itemView;
        imgThumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
        tvspecies = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_species);
        ArrayList<TextView> list = new ArrayList<TextView>();

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                String intentSt = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_species)).getText().toString();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do (maybe you don't need to send the values using intent), but you can do it using putExtra for string array:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(some_action);
intent.putExtra(key, String[] values);
```

If you need to keep reference to each textview you can use the regualrd putExtra(key, String) where the key is the tag you added to your textview or stringify its id.

If you want to get the values dynamically you can use this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
for (int i = 1; i < NUM_OF_TEXT_VIEWS; i++){
   String key = "txtView_" + i;
   int iterTxtViewId = getResources().getIdentifier(key, "id", getPackageName());
   TextView iterTxtView = (TextView)findViewById(iterTxtViewId);
   String value = iterTxtView.getText();

   intent.putExtra(key, value);
   //or
   //String anotherKey = (String)iterTxtView.getTag();
   //intent.putExtra(anotherKey, value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response michael but i getting values dynamically in textview, so i need to get all textview values in array and send the values to another intent

Comment: So you can use the second method i proposed.

Comment: I added a code for dynamic collection of values from TextView (or EditText)

Comment: I am new to android so  please can u able elaborate the second method which u proposed

Comment: The key can be the id of the textview (in the above example all textviews have a prefix of "textView_" or you can use a predefine tag that is set to the view (you can set the tag programatically or within your xml layout file for each textview).

Comment: how can i get the count of text view (i.e) NUM_OF_TEXT_VIEWS

Comment: This is something that you should know if you build the UI. You can also iterate through views children and look for TextViews but I dont think this is what you want. More over this technic already applies that you put a predefined prefix for the textview id so you have to know the number of textviews.

Answer (score 0):

For passing value check this question: [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

Also you can change

```
String intentSt = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_species)).getText().toString();
```

To

```
String intentSt = tvspecies.getText().toString();
```

Comment: thanks to your response, i tried but using this we will get only the current textview value in string. but its really helpful